# How the N-ary association works in class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, tool-uml

- i have three classes and each one of them has an association with same forth class, is it okey to use **N-ary association** in this case ?

Comment: Can you please show a screen shot of that part of your class diagram.

Comment: Your description is not precise enoug  to fully understand the entities you're describing. Can you explain in more details the character of the relations? Maybe provide actual example? Short answer could be - yes, it's OK. But the real question I hear here is - is in my case N-ary association suitable. But the description you've provided is not enough to answer **that** question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML ternary association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917458/uml-ternary-association)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic of your domain. If each of the three classes has a logically separate relationship with the fourth class (i.e. they can vary independently) then they are separate associations. If they are all associated by the same relationship then this would be N-ary. For example, a Car, Driver and Route could be all associated one relationship -- that you might call Journey -- which would be three-ended (N-ary), whereas a Car and an aggregate part (e.g. Wheel) would be two-ended. So it depends.