# UML Ternary Association Implement java Code

Tags: java, class, oop, uml, ooad

ternary association is structural relationship specifies that Object of one thing connected to object of other two's

I understand this relationship but I have no idea how to implement methods that shows association between these three classes.

lets consider following example

- project has number of Developers who use particular programming
  language for development
- developer use particular programming language for develop number of projects
- in selected project one developer use only one programming language

[image: ternary association between project ,developer and programming language]

There exists a ternary association between these three classes.

I've read on different sources regarding this all across the internet and couldn't find a solution

How do I implement above scenario in code (in java) ?

**P.S - Not only this Any other ternary association coding example would be appreciate**

Comment: Other ternary association example: [UML ternary association](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46917458/5221149)

Comment: @ThomasKilian: But the question "UML: how to implement Association class in Java" ***IS NOT*** really a duplicate because ternary associations are not the same as association classes!

Comment: @GerdWagner The basics to implement both in a language are the same. The above is not really a ternary but a simple association class where `Language` is just an attribute of the AC. See the answer of @Andreas below.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I disagree. In the case of the ternary association above, there is no need to represent the association as a separate class. Instead, it can be simply represented/implemented by a complex-valued property like `developersByLanguage`in the `Project` class. The answer of @Andreas is not a good answer to the OP's question. Please reopen the question for giving me the opportunity to post a better answer :-)

Comment: Hm. I guess I can't just re-open. There's a `reopen` button where you can vote.

Comment: i cant reopen the question because view close votes" privilege in order to vote to reopen your own question.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question

Comment: This question shall be reopneded:  The duplicated question is about binary association.  This is very different from a ternary association where there is not just an opposite end, but several opposite ends that have to be considered together. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71281673/3723423

Answer (score 1):

You could use one class to represent the "**Project**". This class has:

-`Map <Developer, Langage>` developers

One class to represent a "**Developer**". This class has:

-`Set<Langage>` langages

-`Set<Projects>` projects

Finally, one class to represent the "**Language**".

```
Class Project {
    Map<Developer, Language> developers = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(Developer developer) {
        developers.put(developer, developer.getLanguage());
        developer.registerOn(this);
    }

Class Developer {

    private Set<Language> languages;  
    private Set<Projects> projects;

    public boolean developIn(Language language) {
       return languages.contains(language);
    }

    public void registerOn(Project project) {
       projects.add(project);
    }
}

Enum Language {
    JAVA,
    PHP;
}
```

Comment: But one requirement is that in a project more than one language may be used!

Comment: I agree with you @GerdWagner. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That UML diagram does not say what you believe it says. The association is an object too.

If you want to specify that *"in selected project one developer use only one programming language"*, then the diagram should be:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that the ternary association model does not imply that "in a project one developer uses only one programming language"?